# Docker-compose erratic parameters reading

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to build a container stack for an application and using the `.env` file so as to pass the various parameters to be used during the build process.

**Stack Config**:

```
    Docker version 20.10.14, build a224086d
    Docker Compose version v2.5.1
    Docker Desktop version 4.8.2 (79419)
.
├── docker
│   ├── php
│   ├── caddy
│── Dockerfile
│── Docker-compose.yml
│── .env
└── README.md
```

The `.env` content:

```
###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
APP_NAME=app
APP_ENV=dev
APP_SECRET=05425c77d4ec3dc1c301c4547ca4ac89
###< symfony/framework-bundle ###

###> docker-compose param ###
SERVER_NAME=${APP_NAME}.local
PHP_VERSION=7.4
COMPOSER_VERSION=2.2.10
CADDY_VERSION=2
HTTP_PROXY=''
APCU_VERSION=5.1
PCOV_VERSION=1.0
XDEBUG_VERSION=3.1.2

MARIABDB_VERSION=10.6
MARIADB_DATABASE=${APP_NAME}_data
MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MARIADB_USER=user
MARIADB_USER_PASSWORD=user
###< docker-composer param ###
```

The `Docker-compose.yaml` file content:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  db:
    container_name: ${APP_NAME:-app}_db
    image: mariadb:${MARIADB_VERSION:-10.6}
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - db_socket:/var/run/mysqld/
    environment:
      MARIADB_INITDB_SKIP_TZINFO: true
      TZ: Europe/Paris
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD:-root}
      MARIADB_DATABASE: ${MARIADB_DATABASE}
      MARIADB_USER: ${MARIADB_USER:-user}
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: ${MARIADB_PASSWORD:-user}

  php:
    container_name: ${APP_NAME:-app}_php
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - db
    build:
      context: .
      target: php_dev
      args:
        PHP_VERSION: ${PHP_VERSION:-7.4}
        COMPOSER_VERSION: ${COMPOSER_VERSION:-2.2.10}
        HTTP_PROXY: ${HTTP_PROXY}
        XDEBUG_VERSION: ${XDEBUG_VERSION:-5.1.2}
    # https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#healthcheck
    healthcheck:
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 30s
    volumes:
      - php_socket:/var/run/php
      - ./app:/srv/app/
    environment:
      # Run "composer require symfony/orm-pack" to install and configure Doctrine ORM
      DATABASE_URL: mysql://${MARIA_USER:-symfony}:${MARIA_USER_PASSWORD:-ChangeMe}@db:3306/${MARIA_DB:-app}?unix_socket=/var/run/mysqld/&serverVersion=${MARIA_VERSION:-10.6}
      # See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host
      # See https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264
      # The `client_host` below may optionally be replaced with `discover_client_host=yes`
      # Add `start_with_request=yes` to start debug session on each request
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: >-
        client_host=host.docker.internal
      XDEBUG_MODE: debug
      # This should correspond to the server declared in PHPStorm `Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Servers`
      # Then PHPStorm will use the corresponding path mappings
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: serverName=symfony
      #      extra_hosts:
      #        # Ensure that host.docker.internal is correctly defined on Linux
      #        - host.docker.internal: host-gateway
      # Run "composer require symfony/mercure-bundle" to install and configure the Mercure integration
      # https://symfony.com/doc/current/mercure.html
      MERCURE_URL: ${CADDY_MERCURE_URL:-http://caddy/.well-known/mercure}
      MERCURE_PUBLIC_URL: https://${SERVER_NAME:-localhost}/.well-known/mercure
      MERCURE_JWT_SECRET: ${CADDY_MERCURE_JWT_SECRET:-!ChangeMe!}


  caddy:
    build:
      context: .
      target: app_caddy
      args:
        CADDY_VERSION: ${CADDY_VERSION:-2}
    depends_on:
      - php
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - php_socket:/var/run/php
      - caddy_data:/data
      - caddy_config:/config
    ports:
      # HTTP
      - target: 80
        published: ${HTTP_PORT:-80}
        protocol: tcp
      # HTTPS
      - target: 443
        published: ${HTTPS_PORT:-443}
        protocol: tcp
      # HTTP/3
      - target: 443
        published: ${HTTP3_PORT:-443}
        protocol: udp
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: ${SERVER_NAME:-localhost, caddy:80}
      MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY: ${CADDY_MERCURE_JWT_SECRET:-!ChangeMe!}
      MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY: ${CADDY_MERCURE_JWT_SECRET:-!ChangeMe!}


volumes:
  php_socket:
  db_socket:
  caddy_data:
  caddy_config:
```

The `Dockerfile` content:

```
ARG PHP_VERSION
ARG CADDY_VERSION
ARG COMPOSER_VERSION
ARG HTTP_PROXY
ARG APCU_VERSION
ARG PCOV_VERSION
ARG XDEBUG_VERSION

# Obliger de charger un https://stackoverflow.com/a/65044947/1374947
FROM composer:${COMPOSER_VERSION} AS composer_local
FROM php:${PHP_VERSION}-fpm-alpine AS php
LABEL "maintainer"="DEIL"
LABEL "version"="1.0"
LABEL "description"="Base image for symfony project"

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apk update; \
    apk upgrade; \
    apk add --no-cache \
        acl \
        bash \
        fcgi \
        file \
        gettext \
        gnu-libiconv \
        nano \
    ;
# install gnu-libiconv and set LD_PRELOAD env to make iconv work fully on Alpine image.
# see https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/240#issuecomment-763112749
ENV LD_PRELOAD /usr/lib/preloadable_libiconv.so
RUN set -eux; \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
        $PHPIZE_DEPS \
        icu-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        zlib-dev \
        mysql-client \
        ldb-dev \
        libldap \
        openldap-dev \
        openldap-clients \
        freetype-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        jpeg-dev \
        libjpeg-turbo-dev \
    ; \
    \
    docker-php-ext-configure zip; \
       docker-php-ext-configure ldap; \
    docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) \
        intl \
        ldap \
        zip \
        pdo_mysql \
        mbstring \
        gd \
    ; \
    pear config-set http_proxy $HTTP_PROXY; \
    pecl install \
    apcu-${APCU_VERSION} \
    ; \
    \
    runDeps="$( \
        scanelf --needed --nobanner --format '%n#p' --recursive /usr/local/lib/php/extensions \
            | tr ',' '\n' \
            | sort -u \
            | awk 'system("[ -e /usr/local/lib/" $1 " ]") == 0 { next } { print "so:" $1 }' \
    )"; \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .phpexts-rundeps $runDeps; \
    \
    apk del .build-deps; \


COPY ./docker/php/docker-healthcheck.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-healthcheck
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-healthcheck
HEALTHCHECK --interval=10s --timeout=3s --retries=3 CMD ["docker-healthcheck"]
# Configuration optimale fournit par PHP-FPM pour le developement
RUN ln -s $PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-development $PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini
COPY docker/php/conf.d/symfony.dev.ini $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/symfony.ini

COPY docker/php/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf

VOLUME /var/run/php

COPY --from=composer_local /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
# https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-allow-superuser
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.composer/vendor/bin"

WORKDIR /srv/app
RUN set -eux; \
    mkdir -p var/cache var/log; \
    ls -halt /srv/app; \
    mkdir -p var/cache var/log; \
    chmod +x bin/console; sync

CMD ["php-fpm"]

# Dockerfile to include xdebug
# https://github.com/dunglas/symfony-docker/blob/main/docs/xdebug.md
FROM php AS php_dev
RUN set -eux; \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps $PHPIZE_DEPS; \
    pecl install xdebug-$XDEBUG_VERSION; \
    docker-php-ext-enable xdebug; \
    apk del .build-deps ; \

FROM php as php_test
# Ajouter la conf pour PCOV - Code Coverage
COPY ./docker/php-test/pcov.ini  /
RUN set -eux; \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps $PHPIZE_DEPS; \
    pecl install pcov-${PCOV_VERSION}; \
    pecl clear-cache; \
    docker-php-ext-enable pcov; \
    cat /pcov.ini >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pcov.ini; \
    apk del .build-deps;

WORKDIR /srv/app
## Copie des sources dans le conteneur.
## Copier le composer.json et .lock et installer les dépendances pendant le build.
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . .

FROM caddy:${CADDY_VERSION}-builder-alpine AS caddy_builder
RUN xcaddy build \
    --with github.com/dunglas/mercure \
    --with github.com/dunglas/mercure/caddy \
    --with github.com/dunglas/vulcain \
    --with github.com/dunglas/vulcain/caddy ;

FROM caddy:${CADDY_VERSION} AS app_caddy
WORKDIR /srv/app

COPY --from=dunglas/mercure:v0.11 /srv/public /srv/mercure-assets/
COPY --from=caddy_builder /usr/bin/caddy /usr/bin/caddy
COPY --from=php /srv/app/public public/
COPY ./docker/caddy/Caddyfile /etc/caddy/Caddyfile
```

Im unable to build the images and assoicated containers; The build returns the following  erratic errors either regarding the format of the version mentionned for the caddy image or the php image :

```
λ docker-compose build --pull --no-cache
[+] Building 0.2s (6/6) FINISHED
 => [skeleton-ci_caddy internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s 
 => [skeleton-ci_php internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s 
 => [skeleton-ci_caddy internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s 
 => [skeleton-ci_php internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s 
 => CANCELED [skeleton-ci_caddy internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/caddy:2-builder-alpine                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s 
 => CANCELED [skeleton-ci_caddy internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/caddy:2                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s 
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to parse stage name "php:-fpm-alpine": invalid reference format
```

Im unable to locate the probable cause of this erractic error an correct it.
Am I missing something?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#scope

"An ARG instruction goes out of scope at the end of the build stage where it was defined. To use an arg in multiple stages, each stage must include the ARG instruction."

Comment: Thanks , I'm reviewing the dockerfile accordingly.